# Hibernate native query return integer list not working

Tags: hibernate, native

I am using native query in hibernate and it will return me list of id. I want to convert this list in to integer list. But it is not working and showing me the exception.

```
public List<Integer> fethcSurvayIdOnCount(){
            HibernateCallback action = new HibernateCallback() {
            public Object doInHibernate(Session session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        String hq = "select id from tb_abc where age='10'" ;

        SQLQuery query = (SQLQuery) session
                .createSQLQuery(hq)
                .setResultTransformer(
                        Transformers
                                .aliasToBean(Integer.class));

        return query.list();
    }
    };
    return (List<Integer>) getHibernateTemplate()
        .execute(action);
    }
```

Here  is the exception

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Could not find setter for id on class java.lang.Integer; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for id on class java.lang.Integer
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:676)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This quetion is quite easy. first, if you use native SQL, the returned result sets are object arrays, and the first element in each array is your id value, so the method's return-value should be List,  here is a example:

```
public List<Object[]> getIds(){ 

    String hq = "select id from tb_abc where age='10'" ;
    List<Object[]> results = session.createSQLQuery(hq).list();

    return results;
```

}

After you get the results, you can get your expected values like following:

```
for(Object[] obj : results) {
     Integer id = Integer.valueOf(obj[0].toString());
     // do sth
}
```

Comment: I've tried this first but then I did my answer which is easier.

Answer (score 3):

This is better. No conversion is required from Object to Integer in a loop:

```
public List<Integer> getIds(){ 

    String hq = "select id from tb_abc where age='10'" ;
    List<Integer> results = session.createSQLQuery(hq).list();

    return results;
}
```

I am using hibernate 4.3

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your `Transfomer`. As you are requesting a specific field what you get from the list Method is a `List<Object[]>` and you transformer tries to map those object into an integer but based on the alias of the properties ("id" in your case) and assuming that the class you specified is a bean (thus the name of the method `aliasToBean`) which `Integer` is not.

You may have to iterate through the list returned by the query to get in the right Type (which is what a transformer does under the hood anyway).